# "Automatic" simulation of distribution in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 10 sets of 1,000 historical values, some of which are normally distributed, others non-normally (per Jarque-Bera test). I would now like to simulate 1,000 values based on the distribution of each set. Is it possible to have a formula that works for both normal AND non-normal distributions, i.e. the simulated distribution will have the same skewness and kurtosis of the sample, regardless of normality or non-normality?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with your "Jarque-Bera test" at all and I don't know what normal distribution formula you might be using. Nonetheless, it should be eminently possible to submit the same skewness and kurtosis to two different functions ... assuming they both use skewness and kurtosis.

Assuming your functions looked something like this:

```
=SomeNormalFunction(u, v, w, kurtosis, skewness, x, y, z)
```

and

```
=NonNormalFunction(p, q, kurtosis, skewness, r, s, t)
```

you could simply give the same cell for the kurtosis value in each formula.

```
cell A1: [some value of kurtosis]
cell B1: [some value of skewness]
cell C1: =SomeNormalFunction(u, v, w, A1, B1, x, y, z)
cell D1: =NonNormalFunction(p, q, A1, B1, r, s, t)
```

This seems so self-evident that I suspect I have probably misunderstood your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using norminv. I understand what you mean, however, I am looking for a generic non-normal function.